# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: myorders.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, bootstrap-4

I have tried a spinner for the delay in loading data.
Please let me know where is the wrong. I am using MongoDB, and the server is my local server computer.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col, Button, Carousel, Spinner } from 'react-bootstrap';
import useAuth from '../../../Authorization/hooks/useAuth';
import '../../../Style/style.css';


const Order = () => {

    const { user, loading } = useAuth();
    const [myorders, setMyOrders] = useState({});
    const [singleItem, setSingleItem] = useState({});

    console.log(myorders);


    useEffect(() => {
        const url = `http://localhost:5000/myorders/?email=${user?.email}`
        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => setMyOrders(data))
    }, []);


    const handleDelete = (id) => {
        const proceed = window.confirm('Do you really want to remove this item!');

        if (proceed) {
            const url = `http://localhost:5000/cars/${id}`;
            fetch(url, {
                method: 'DELETE'
            })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    if (data.deletedCount > 0) {
                        alert('Deleted Successfully!');
                        const remainingUsers = myorders.filter(item => item._id !== id);
                        setMyOrders(remainingUsers);
                    }

                });
        }
    }

    const totalCar = myorders.length;

    if (loading) {
        return <Spinner animation="border" />
    }


    return (
        <Container>
            <Row>
                <Col lg={12}>
                    {
                        totalCar == 0 ?
                        // <Spinner animation="border" />

                            <h6>Please select any car.</h6>
                            :
                            <h6>There are {totalCar} cars waiting to go into your garage!</h6>
                    }

                        <Row>
                            <Col>
                                {
                                    myorders.map(order =>
                                        // {key={order._id}}
                                        <div className='order_items'>
                                            <Row>
                                                <Col lg={4}>
                                                    <div className='item_img'>
                                                        <Carousel>
                                                            <Carousel.Item>
                                                                <img
                                                                    className="d-block w-100"
                                                                    src={order.img[1]}
                                                                    alt="First Image"
                                                                />
                                                            </Carousel.Item>
                                                            <Carousel.Item>
                                                                <img
                                                                    className="d-block w-100"
                                                                    src={order.img[2]}
                                                                    alt="Second Image"
                                                                />
                                                            </Carousel.Item>
                                                            <Carousel.Item>
                                                                <img
                                                                    className="d-block w-100"
                                                                    src={order.img[3]}
                                                                    alt="Third Image"
                                                                />
                                                            </Carousel.Item>
                                                            <Carousel.Item>
                                                                <img
                                                                    className="d-block w-100"
                                                                    src={order.img[4]}
                                                                    alt="Third Image"
                                                                />
                                                            </Carousel.Item>
                                                            <Carousel.Item>
                                                                <img
                                                                    className="d-block w-100"
                                                                    src={order.img[5]}
                                                                    alt="Third Image"
                                                                />
                                                            </Carousel.Item>
                                                            <Carousel.Item>
                                                                <img
                                                                    className="d-block w-100"
                                                                    src={order.img[6]}
                                                                    alt="Third Image"
                                                                />
                                                            </Carousel.Item>
                                                        </Carousel>
                                                    </div>
                                                </Col>
                                                <Col lg={8}>

                                                    <div className='item_info'>
                                                        <h5>{order.name}</h5>
                                                        <h6>Price: ${order.price}</h6>
                                                        <h6>Location: {order.location}</h6>
                                                        <h6>Mileage: {order.mileage}</h6>
                                                        <h6>Fuel: {order.fuel}</h6>
                                                        <Button onClick={() => handleDelete(order._id)}>Remove</Button>
                                                        {/* <Button onClick={() => handlePay(order._id)}>Pay</Button> */}
                                                    </div>
                                                </Col>
                                            </Row>
                                        </div>
                                    )
                                }
                            </Col>
                        </Row>

                </Col>
            </Row>

        </Container>
    );
};


export default Order;
```

Comment: `myorders` starts off life as an (empty) object which does not have a `map` method - we dont know what it is after you have loaded the data!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are trying to `.map` over something which is not an array, because at the top of your file you initialize it as an object, so the first time you go to render it can't map it.

`const [myorders, setMyOrders] = useState({});`

**Should be**

`const [myorders, setMyOrders] = useState([]);`

Comment: I have tried this too

Comment: I have tried this too(const [myorders, setMyOrders] = useState([]);) but same result.

Answer (score 0):

The golden rule of React is that **"React will not wait to render"**. So you're calling Array `map` on an object on the first render because your `myOrders` property is initialized with an object and `map` doesn't exist on objects, only arrays.

If you initialize your `myOrders` useState with an empty array first eg:

`const [myOrders, setMyOrders] = useState([])`

then map will be there but will not run on the first render because the array is empty. Which is good. It's better than a crash.

Then when your orders come in and get set into `myOrders` React will render again because changes to useState cause a re-render.

As a safety precaution and a UI/UX benefit to the user also you can check if there's anything in `myOrders` before rendering the table and running map on it. Something like this in your return:

`{ myOrders.length ? <MyTable orders={ myOrders }/> : <p>No Orders</p> }`

You can also check this just before accessing map on it in your current example like this:

`myOrders.length && myOrders.map(order =>` ...etc